# How to find and replace dictionary values which is present in list

Tags: python-3.x

```
complex_result = ['In the 2000s , operating systems such as ncp1 Android  flourished for mobile ncp2 known', 'as apps became commonplace']
res_dict = {'rep_sentence': 'In the 2000s, operating systems such as ncp1 Android flourished for mobile ncp2 known as apps became commonplace.', 'replacements': [{'replacedPhrase': 'Apple iOS and Google', 'replacement': 'ncp1'}, {'replacedPhrase': 'devices, and programs', 'replacement': 'ncp2'}]}

for each_rep in res_dict['replacements']:
    res = [masked_np.replace(each_rep['replacement'],each_rep['replacedPhrase']) if 
            each_rep['replacement'] in masked_np else masked_np for masked_np in 
             complex_result]
print("res>>",res)
```

Actual output = ['In the 2000s , operating systems such as ncp1 Android  flourished for mobile devices, and programs known', 'as apps became commonplace']

Expected output = ['In the 2000s , operating systems such as Apple iOS and Google Android  flourished for mobile devices, and programs known.']

Comment: You are *overwriting* the value of `res` for each iteration of your loop.  So, on each replacement, you are throwing away the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

```
complex_result = ''.join(complex_result[0]) #convert list to string
for i in res_dict['replacements']:
    complex_result = complex_result.replace(i['replacement'], i['replacedPhrase'])
complex_result = complex_result.split(maxsplit=0)
```

---

**Explanation:**

First we convert list to string using the join method 
`join` is method for string that take iterable as parameter and make it string and add text between every iterable , example:

```
x = ['Dog', 'Cat']
print('and'.join(x)) #Result : DogandCat
```

ops we forgot to add space, lets add space:

```
print(' and '.join(x))` #Result: Dog and Cat
```

So when we use `''.join()` it will just convert it to string [More Info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-list-to-string/)

Then we iterable the res_dict with 'replacements' key
so it will iterable this :

```
{'replacedPhrase': 'Apple iOS and Google', 'replacement': 'ncp1'}
{'replacedPhrase': 'devices, and programs', 'replacement': 'ncp2'}
```

than we just replace 'replacement' with 'replacedPhrase', so first it will replace 'ncp1' with 'Apple iOS and Google'

Finally we use split method with `maxsplit=0` to convert string to list
maxsplit parameter is the number of how many words will iterable and append them to list ? 'a b c d'.split(maxsplit=1) this will append a only and "extend" bcd into one sentence ['a','b c d'] its determine by spaces, by default maxsplit equal to -1 it mean all the words, example:

```
'cat is faster than dog'.split() #result: ['cat', 'is', 'faster', 'than', 'dog']
'cat is faster than dog'.split(maxsplit=2) #result: ['cat', 'is', 'faster than dog']`
```

[More Info](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem the OP has, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looping over each of the replacements, you are *overwriting* your value of `res`.  This means that each loop, when you are doing that replacement, you are throwing away the previous replacement.

Also, you don't need to check `if each_rep['replacement'] in masked_np` before doing the `.replace()`.  If the string is not there, then `.replace()` will not do anything.

---

A different way to do this could be to use a combination of `map()` and `functools.reduce()` (in python 2, this was just `reduce()`.

```
from functools import reduce

complex_result = ['In the 2000s , operating systems such as ncp1 Android  flourished for mobile ncp2 known', 'as apps became commonplace']
res_dict = {'rep_sentence': 'In the 2000s, operating systems such as ncp1 Android flourished for mobile ncp2 known as apps became commonplace.', 'replacements': [{'replacedPhrase': 'Apple iOS and Google', 'replacement': 'ncp1'}, {'replacedPhrase': 'devices, and programs', 'replacement': 'ncp2'}]}

res = map(lambda v: reduce(lambda s, r: s.replace(r['replacement'], r['replacedPhrase']), res_dict['replacements'], v), complex_result)

print("res>>", list(res))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJNa8MwDIbv@RWilyQQStfdCiv0NHbaYMcQimsrjZltGdvpVkp/e6aM9pDSsd2sr1ePJPtj6sg9DkMbyELbO5mITARtPYUEAVUvMcskWW/waxsw9ibBE9T5i4PUISwXi0WECshjEEm7PcRjTGgjxF52ICI46R9g41QgrQBaQ33QsUMFLQWwtNMGx5wlfDj6dHkFORcJ7yPsUAqLwM0tOW@ExLzJGGGrtBwhTnlAv43oEjqOrWAC9W@mv5Dgd575iMsQ49syR2SI@nT1qLcuiPgDtvG8P9Cv7yCcgmeivcGb2jFt5MrPFdyTUHjQEnmsUcEH2gdh432NZX5uztm4Kt6SFb4wwu6UgMPqctGrg9XCCuL8IlGEeqLWcLi@RWlK9l6OUE@H5/wDR6e/pcwyH7RLxYzt9XpWgdExFWyU5TB8Aw)

---

To fix your current code, you need to make sure you are running the `.replace()` on the updated string/list from each loop.  Something like this:

```
complex_result = ['In the 2000s , operating systems such as ncp1 Android  flourished for mobile ncp2 known', 'as apps became commonplace']
res_dict = {'rep_sentence': 'In the 2000s, operating systems such as ncp1 Android flourished for mobile ncp2 known as apps became commonplace.', 'replacements': [{'replacedPhrase': 'Apple iOS and Google', 'replacement': 'ncp1'}, {'replacedPhrase': 'devices, and programs', 'replacement': 'ncp2'}]}

res = complex_result.copy()
for each_rep in res_dict['replacements']:
    res = [masked_np.replace(each_rep['replacement'], each_rep['replacedPhrase']) for masked_np in res]

print("res>>",res)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE/a8MwEMV3f4pHFiVgTJpugQYylU4tdDTGKNIlFrH@IDltQ8hnd6UmHtymtFokne7e/e7JHbvGmvu@F1a7lj5qT@HQdnhAyZ4MuoawmM/nATmsI887ZXYIx9CRDggH0YAHGOHusDbSWyWBbWsPXoWGJLbWQ9uNainlLLA39t2wHCwWcecCNiS4JsTm2hrXckGsyiJCLZVIECfmydWBTEcmvi0xgvo3019I@J2nSLgRIp115AgRojwNEfnSeB6@wNYu@gf1/ApuJB6t3bX0rTalJS52znFLQtKbEhTHSgrO253nOtzWWLBzdc6SVdGl8d8VwrrjdJalSYmLJoYdlMFgazkep1pmiOuiVGoe9iRr44pr0nSQGJWxKsePh2GSanZxeZC6Nq@yzHlluukkXlarSR63Wd9/Ag)